# Stored Procedure set parameter based on other parameters input

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters

Trying to create a stored procedure in SQL 2008R2.
I have two Parameter inputs, that depending on their input, will ideally set another parameter's value to one of four values.  Trying to determine if this can done, and if so, where is the best place to put it in the SP.
Here is a slimmed down version of my code.

```
Declare @FWIdle as bYN, @NewComp as bYN

set @FW = 'Y'           
set @NEW = 'Y'  

select Case(
when w.WearRate <0.400 then round((- 50*w.WearRate+112.5),2
when w.WearRate <0.450 then round((-100*w.WearRate+132.5),2)
when w.WearRate <0.550 then round((- 50*w.WearRate+110.5),2)
else 52.5 END as Score

from EMWear w
```

Hoping to replace all w.WearRate with @Wear and setting @Wear to one of four possible fields in the view, based on the combination of the two parameters.

So something like:

```
if @FW = 'Y' and @NEW = 'N' then @Wear = w.FWRate else
if @FW = 'N' and @NEW = 'Y' then @Wear = w.NewRate else
if @FW = 'Y' and @NEW = 'Y' then @Wear = w.FWNewRate else
@Wear = w.WearRate
```

Since I have 150+ lines of code that deals with this rate, I would prefer not to have to write this code 4 times to get the desired Value. Any help on how I can write this and keep it clean/simple would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce all of your code to something like this.

```
SELECT w.EMCo, w.Component,w.CompType, CASE 
WHEN @FW = 'Y' AND @NEW = 'Y' THEN w.FwIdleWearRate
WHEN @FW = 'Y' AND @NEW = 'N' THEN w.FwWearRate
WHEN @FW = 'N' AND @NEW = 'Y' THEN w.IdleWearRate
ELSE w.StdWearRate
END AS WearRate
FROM bcvEMCompWearAdj w
```

Comment: That would pull the correct WearRate in, but not show how that would work for the multiple lines of calculations I use with that WearRate.
Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem ended up being to create a temp table and insert the WearRate that I wanted to use.

```
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempWear','U') IS NOT NULL 
Drop Table #TempWear;

Create Table #TempWear 
    EMCo tinyint Null,
    Component varchar(10) NULL,
    CompType varchar(10) NULL,
    WearRate decimal(38,5) NULL
    );

if @FW = 'Y' and @New = 'Y'
Begin
    Insert into #TempWear
    (EMCo, Component, CompType, WearRate)
    select w.EMCo, w.Component,w.CompType, w.FwIdleWearRate 
    from bcvEMCompWearAdj w
END
else 
if @FW = 'Y' and @New = 'N'
Begin
    Insert into #TempWear
    (EMCo, Component, CompType, WearRate)
    select w.EMCo, w.Component,w.CompType, w.FwWearRate 
    from bcvEMCompWearAdj w
END
else
if @FW = 'N' and @New = 'Y'
Begin
    Insert into #TempWear
    (EMCo, Component, CompType, WearRate)
    sselect w.EMCo, w.Component,w.CompType, w.IdleWearRate
    from bcvEMCompWearAdj w
END
else
--if @FW = 'N' and @New = 'N'
Begin
    Insert into #TempWear
    (EMCo, Component, CompType, WearRate)
    select w.EMCo, w.Component,w.CompType, w.StdWearRate    
    from bcvEMCompWearAdj w
END
```